# Google Apps Script: Google Sheet not updating

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I am creating a script that analyzes emails containing the subject "INTERAC e-Transfer", reads a name (sender) and a number (amount sent by sender) and updates a Google Sheet with that number. For example, block A1 contains the name "John" and the email reads something along the lines "INTERAC e-Transfer John Doe sent in $100", then block B1 will be updated to 100. As of now, it seems that when running the function `updateSheetOnETransfer` the unread email is then read but the Sheet is not updated. Here's the current code so far:

```js
function getCellForName(sheet, name) {
  var nameRanges = ['C5:C16', 'C18:C35'];
  var offset = 3; // Column F is 3 columns to the right of Column C

  for (var i = 0; i < nameRanges.length; i++) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(nameRanges[i]);
    var values = range.getValues();

    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      if (values[j][0].trim().toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) {
        var row = range.getRow() + j;
        var column = range.getColumn() + offset;
        return sheet.getRange(row, column);
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function updateSheetOnETransfer() {
  var sheetId = 'id';
  var sheetName = 'S23 - Payment Progress Tracker';

  var query = 'label:inbox is:unread "INTERAC e-Transfer"';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      if (messages[j].isUnread()) {
        var subject = messages[j].getSubject();
        var body = messages[j].getPlainBody();

        // Extract relevant data from the email
        var sender = messages[j].getFrom();
        var receivedDate = messages[j].getDate();

        // Parse the email body to get the e-transfer amount and sender's name
        // Adjust the regex as needed based on your e-transfer email format
        var amountRegex = /(?:has sent you)\s*\$([\d.,]+)/i;
        var nameRegex = /(?:has sent you)\s*[\d.,]+\s*\(CAD\)\s*from\s*([\w\s]+)(?=\s)/i;

        var amountMatch = body.match(amountRegex);
        var nameMatch = body.match(nameRegex);

        var amount = amountMatch ? parseFloat(amountMatch[1]) : 0;
        var name = nameMatch ? nameMatch[1] : '';

        if (name) {
          var cell = getCellForName(sheet, name);
          if (cell) {
            cell.setValue(amount);
          }
        }

        // Mark the message as read
        messages[j].markRead();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the updateSheetOnETransfer function runs periodically. You can use Google Apps Script triggers to schedule the automatic execution of the function at regular intervals or at a specific time.